# Trouble when making a HTTPS request

Tags: java, php, android, https, android-asynctask

I have this async task:

```
public class likeTheJoke extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{        

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://site.com/android/jokes/updateLikes.php");

        try {
             // Add data
            String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode("Joke 7", "UTF-8"); // recently added after a comment suggestion
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jokeName", encodedUrl));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }       
}
```

I'm trying to pass a parameter to my php script and to update a value in the database.
With the code above my link should be looking like: `https://site.com/android/jokes/updateLikes.php?jokeName=Joke 7`

The problem is that after the request, nothing is happening. I know that it's normal, because of the `HTTPS`, but I really can't find a way to make the request working, even when there are about 10 answers here. Can you guid me and tell me what I'm missing? I know that it is something really small, but I'm not able to spot it.

Here is my php code(just an additional info):

```
<?php
$jokeName = urldecode($_GET["jokeName"]); // urldecode added after a comment suggestion.

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE JOKES SET likes = likes+1
WHERE jokeName='$jokeName'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**P.S** I have changed the site name and DB details in teh posted code.

Comment: do you realize that you have a space between Joke and 7 ?

Comment: @blackbelt Code edited. Same issue is happening. + `UrlEncodedFormEntity` should do the job.

Comment: how are you sure nothing is happening?

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx The value in the DB is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is in trouble with the same issue, here is how i fixed it:

```
    try{
                String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode("name with spaces", "UTF-8");
                URL url = new URL("https://site.com/android/dir/file.php?paramName="+encodedUrl);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

in php you need to escape and decode the parameter from the url like:

```
$categoryParam= mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_GET["Param"]));
```

It might not be the best way to do it, but it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "url encoding" to make sure the blank in your target string is properly converted.

Comment: I just edited the java and php code. The same issue is happening. Also `UrlEncodedFormEntity` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a post with the `jokeName=joke 7` as the post body (entity).  But on the php side, you're trying to get it as a GET param (url parameter). So the joke id is not passed to the PHP side.

Some simple logging on php side should reveal this.

Either add the `jokeName=Joke 7` as a url parameter, or use `$_POST['jokeName']` on the php side.